# SQL Finding MAX number in a VARCHAR typed column

Tags: php, sql, select, numbers, max

I have got SQL table where I have column DISTANCE (varchar50). It's number with dot.

```
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| ID | USERID | MONTH  | DISTANCE |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 1  |    1   | 201707 |   7.25   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 2  |    2   | 201707 |   9.17   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 3  |    2   | 201707 |  10.31   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
| 4  |    1   | 201706 |  10.08   |
+----+--------+--------+----------+
```

I would like to display MAX value od DISTANCE. If I ORDER BY distance DESC the result is:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY distance DESC
9.17
7.25
10.31
10.08
```

I try to find the MAX but still is not correct

```
SELECT MAX(distance) AS mvzd FROM mytable
9.17
```

How I can have correct max distance value which should be `10.31` with the provided sample data ?

Comment: I feel like mysql would cast your string to a double if possible and then correctly display 10.31. Are you sure you don't have any spaces in your DISTANCE column or something that would prevent mysql from casting?

Comment: Can you change your column to a data type that matches your data (like decimal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PROBLEM](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46f0cf/1)

[SOLUTION](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46f0cf/2)

You can use the following query :

```
select max(cast(distance as decimal(10,2))) AS mvzd FROM mytable
```

By your existing query, you are finding `MAX` on a `VARCHAR` typed column and you are getting correct result what you wrote! If you want to have your desired result, first you have to convert the type of that column like i did in the above query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use **wrong data type** of the `DISTANCE`. In your case you store the distance values as `varchar` and that's why the `ORDER BY` and `MAX()` functions does not work as expected - in this case the `ORDER BY` is sorting values as a string from the very first character. In your example you tried to sorted in descending order to be like from lowest to larger - this will give you "unexpected" results if there will be value like 98.76 or 111.15.

All you need is to set the data type of `DISTANCE` column to **`float`** - a small number with a floating decimal point.

Change settings of your table to use `float`:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable`
  CHANGE COLUMN `distance` `distance` 
  FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `month`;
```

Data stored as `float` will support all native functions such as MIN, MAX, ORDER BY etc. which will work as expected without any workarounds.

Here is corrected example using `float`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f8692/1
Here is extended example using incorrect `varchar(50)`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4da754e/1